# Fullpage.js image fadein after section load

Tags: image, callback, fadein, fullpage.js

i'm trying to have img fadein effect after section has been loaded (something like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNGdvr but with section instead of slides). I set img display:none in the 3rd section of my fullpage, then I tried using afterload but it doesn't work. I'm not so good with coding, can please anyone help me? Many thanks!

```js
//fullpage.js//
new fullpage('#enlabs', {
  anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3'],
  sectionsColor: ['white', '#f0dd03', '#FFF'],
  autoScrolling:true,
  css3:true,
  lazyLoading: true,
  scrollOverflow: false,
  lockAnchors: true,
  verticalCentered: true,
  
      afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
      var loadedSlide = $(this).find('img');
      loadedSlide.fadeIn();
    },

});
```

```css
/* stile div fullscreen */
.fullscreen {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   width: 100%;
   display:block;
}

/* stile immagine fullscreen */
.fullscreen img {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   object-fit: cover;
}


/* stile div con padding */
.border {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  margin: 135px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-height: calc(100vh - (135px*2));
  max-height: calc(100vh - (135px*2));
}

/* stile immagine con padding */
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
.border img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<!-- inizio fullpage --> 
<div id="enlabs">
  
  
  <!-- inizio sezione 1 -->
<div class="section">
         <div class="slide fullscreen"> 
   <picture>
    <source media="(orientation:portrait)" data-srcset="https://www.spazio.studio/wp-content/uploads/2019/enlabs/ENL_01_vert_low.jpg">
  <img data-src="https://www.spazio.studio/wp-content/uploads/2019/img_nuove/enlabs/ENL_02.jpg" data-sizes="auto">
</picture>
        </div>
</div>
<!-- fine sezione 1 --> 
  
  
  
<!-- inizio sezione 2 --> 
   <div class="section testo">LUISS EnLabs è un acceleratore che offre agli studenti universitari la possibilità di trasformare la propria startup digitale in una realtà imprenditoriale mettendo a disposizione un finanziamento iniziale, una prestigiosa location al centro di Roma e l’esperienza di imprenditori e manager di successo che operano come tutor.
    </div>
<!-- fine sezione 2 --> 
   
  
  <!-- inizio sezione 3 -->
<div class="section">
         <div class="slide fullscreen"> 
   <picture>
    <source media="(orientation:portrait)" data-srcset="https://www.spazio.studio/wp-content/uploads/2019/enlabs/ENL_02_vert.gif">
  <img data-src="https://www.spazio.studio/wp-content/uploads/2019/enlabs/ENL_02.gif" data-sizes="auto"  style="display:none">
</picture>
        </div>
</div>
<!-- fine sezione 3 --> 
  

 

<script src='https://www.spazio.studio/wp-content/uploads/jquery-3.2.1.js'></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.spazio.studio/wp-content/uploads/fullpage.css" />

<script src='https://www.spazio.studio/wp-content/uploads/jquery.easing.min.js'></script>

<script src='https://www.spazio.studio/wp-content/uploads/fullpage.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the latest fullPage.js version 3 you can get from [the Github repository](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullpage.js/archive/master.zip).
Notice you'll need a license you can get from the [fullpage.js pricing page](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/pricing/).

Then you can use the afterLoad callback as detailed in the [the fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)

```
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],

    afterLoad: function(origin, destination, direction){
        var loadedSection = this;

        //using index
        if(origin.index == 2){
            alert("Section 3 ended loading");
        }

        //using anchorLink
        if(origin.anchor == 'secondSlide'){
            alert("Section 2 ended loading");
        }
    }
});
```

[Example online](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/XbPNQv)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have two other question :). First of all, i can't understand how to update fullpage (my fault). Second is that I used afterload but it doesn't work.

  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
  var loadedSlide = $(this).find('img');
  loadedSlide.fadeIn();
},
I tried the afterload code you pasted and it works well, so i think the problem is with my code. Can you give me more specific help? I'm a very very basic coder.

Thanks again!

Comment: To update just go to the page and click Download https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/
AfterLoad example working [on Github](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/callbacks-v3.html).

If you need further support consider getting a premium support package with the Organization license. We'll happily help you out! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! 
I have two other question :). 
First of all, i can't understand how to update fullpage (my fault).
Second is that I used afterload but it doesn't work.

```
  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
  var loadedSlide = $(this).find('img');
  loadedSlide.fadeIn();
},
```

I tried the afterload code you pasted and it works well, so i think the problem is with my code. Can you give me more specific help? I'm a very very basic coder.

Thanks again!